# Function not being called by onkeypress()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, controller, textarea

I have a task to not let a user type "%" in a textArea, therefore i did this

But once I click inside the text area, I can still type '%'... which means that **onkeypress** isn't recognizing my function, or the function itself is wrong.

```js
$scope.test = function() {
  var txtarea = document.getElementById("exampleFormControlTextarea1");
  txtarea.addEventListener("input", function() {
    txtarea.value = txtarea.value.replaceAll("%", "");
  })
}
```

I also tried this way:

```js
function myfunction () {
        var txtarea = document.getElementById("exampleFormControlTextarea1");
        txtarea.addEventListener("input", function() {
            txtarea.value = txtarea.value.replaceAll("%", "");
        })
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 label-base">

  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Justify</label>
  <textarea style="resize: none" ng-disabled="negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.flagDesabilitaEdicaoProposta" 
  class="form-control observacoes" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" 
  ng-model="negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.dadosCadastro.negociacaoEspecial.justificativaNegociacaoEspecial"
    onkeypress="test()"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't add an event listener inside a function that is already an event listener.

Comment: So after getElementById... i remove 'txtarea.addEventListener("input", function() ' and only let ' txtarea.value = txtarea.value.replaceAll("%", "");' ?

Comment: @PedroPastori I'd also remove the `txtarea.addEventListener...`. That's not really the AngularJS way of doing things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restrict Special Characters in HTML & AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005810/restrict-special-characters-in-html-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is [ngKeypress](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress) here

you can call your function on ngKeypress like this. I took the liberty of renaming your ng-model object to model here, because your one is too long

```
<div class="col-md-12 label-base">

  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Justify</label>
  <textarea style="resize: none" ng-disabled="negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.flagDesabilitaEdicaoProposta" 
  class="form-control observacoes" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" 
  ng-model="model"
    ng-keypress="test()"></textarea>
</div>
```

Since your textarea has an ng-model, you should change your method to this instead

```
$scope.test = function() {
   console.log("Method called");
   $scope.model = $scope.model.replaceAll("%", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35777284/1772933

Use a filter together with a ng-change function, like:

```
angular.module("test", [])
    .filter("purger", function() {
        return function(input) {
            return input.replace(/%/gi, "");
        }
    }).controller("testController", function($scope, purgerFilter) {
        $scope.onChange = function() {
            $scope.negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.dadosCadastro.negociacaoEspecial.justificativaNegociacaoEspecial = purgerFilter($scope.negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.dadosCadastro.negociacaoEspecial.justificativaNegociacaoEspecial);
        }
    })
```

and your element:

```
<textarea ... 
ng-model="negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.dadosCadastro.negociacaoEspecial.justificativaNegociacaoEspecial"
ng-change="onChange()"></textarea>
```